# Adjoint operator on subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $T:V_1 \to V_2$ be linear with adjoint $T^*:V_2^* \to V_1^*$. Suppose $V_i \subset H_i \subset V_i^*$ is a Hilbert triple.

Let $f \in H_2 \subset V_2^*$. How can I interpret $T^*f$? Is it just $T^{-1}f$?

Comment: What do you mean interpret? Also, how could it possibly be $Tf$ when $f \in V_2^*$ while $T$ acts on the elements from $V_1$? This expression would not make any sense. Is there something you are not telling us?

Comment: @Marek It should be $T^{-1}f$. I thought there should be some simplification since $f$ lies in a nicer space.

Comment: That's not much better for two reasons. First, $f$ can belong to $H_2 \setminus V_2$, so the expression is again not defined and second, $T$ need not be either injective or surjective, so $T^{-1}$ is not defined in general and even when it is, not for all $f \in V_2$. I think not much can be said about your question unless you add more requirements either on some of the spaces or on the map $T$.